# Custom ConfigSource in DeltaSpike

Tags: deltaspike

How do I create a custom `ConfigSource` in DeltaSpike that read config data from legacy code?

Does DeltaSpike also support configuration changes? i.e. the injected value will get changed when the underlying configuration has been changed

Answer (score 0):

See http://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation/configuration.html#_custom_configsources
[@Inject + @ConfigProperty] leads to dependent values.
-> If you are using them e.g. in @ApplicationScoped beans, you only get the value once (by definition).
If you are using them e.g. in a @RequestScoped bean, you will always get the latest value. 
With using ConfigResolver manually, you will always get the latest value as well.
Everything else (including caching values) is up to your own ConfigSource implementation.